# how to tell ActiveModelSerialer to not encode an attribute because it is already json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

Is there a way to tell Active Model Serializer in the 0.8 branchto not encode an attribute because it is already in JSON format. The data was cached as JSON.

Something like the `already_json` at the end below:

```
class MetroAreaSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :metro_area, :metro_locations  #, :copy #, :menu_item, :location
  def metro_locations
    Queryable.where("metro_area_id=? and queryable_type=?",id,'Location').map(&:result_json).to_s.already_json
  end
end
```

Comment: What does `result_json` returns? String or hash?

Comment: it returns a string which is prebuilt json - I could join(',') on the array of strings but I would need a way to tell AMS not to encode it again (I think)

Comment: What you need is to return a hash, could you show how this method is defined?

Comment: @BroiSatse  yea, I'd like to prevent that behavior - deserializing / reserializing is really slow